# Routing in Codeigniter with HMVC

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, url, routes, hmvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Codeigniter HVMC modular seperation extension URL rewrite / routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380174/codeigniter-hvmc-modular-seperation-extension-url-rewrite-routing)

I am new to codeigniter HMVC. I currently have four modules which are as follows:

/application/modules/

**+Site**

- models
- views
- controllers

**+Login**

...

**+Members**

...

**+Admin**

...

The '**site**' module is the default module that user view on arrival to my website. My only problem is that I am unhappy having the controller name '**Site**' in each one of my urls.

Example:

- http://www.mywebsite/site/services
- http://www.mywebsite/site/products

How can I change the route so that the 'site' controller is no longer visible in my urls and I can still access the /members, /login and /admin controllers??

What is the method for doing so? Can't find a solution anywhere.

Should I just keep the site as mvc structure in the standard CI format????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also move everything from your default module to the default /controllers, /models and /views folders under the /application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should modify your .htaccess rather than routes:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^site/ /$1 [NC]
```